# Minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be a square matrix with real entries such that $A^2=-I$ where $I$ is the corresponding identity matrix. Prove that $det(A)=1$.

Remarks - I solved this using the basics of vector spaces.
Also, someone told me a solution using eigenvalues. The two solutions can be seen at the below link.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c953773h2292285_a_minimalistic_minimal_polynomial

Is there a 'simpler' solution?

Comment: I would say that your "vector space" solution is already the simplest.

Comment: What are the *basics* of vector spaces?

Comment: I believe this is the simplest way to prove that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof that is simpler and shorter than the first proof in the link.

1. The matrix $A$ is similar to a  complex matrix $B$ in Jordan normal form. The diagonal entries of $B$ (eigenvalues of $A$) satisfy $\alpha^2=-1$, so they are equal $\pm i$.
2. It is easy to see that if $C$ is a Jordan block of size $>1$ then $C^2\ne -I$, so $B$ is a diagonal matrix.
3. Since $A$ has real entries, its (multiset of) eigenvalues can be partitioned into
   pairs $(i, -i)$: for every eigenvalue $\pm i$ there is eigenvalue $\mp i$. This implies that the product of eigenvalues of $A$ is $1$ (because $i\cdot (-i)=1$). Hence $\det A=1$

Comment: This is not shorter or simpler than the second proof provided in the link

Comment: I did not notice the second proof. My solution actually gives slightly more information: the matrix $A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix with $n$ diagonal entries $i$ and $n$ diagonal entries $-i$.

Comment: I agree with that. However, providing more information does not make a proof simpler

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that avoids (directly) considering complex eigenvalues.

First, note (as in the first answer) that the size $n$ of $A$ is even since $0 < \det(A)^2 = \det(-I) = (-1)^n$, as in the answer. We also see that $|\det(A)|^2 = 1$, which means that $|\det(A)| = 1$.

Consider the real polynomial $\det(tI - A)$. I claim that it cannot have any real roots. Indeed, if $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$ for some real $\lambda$, then there must be a non-zero solution to $(\lambda I - A)x  = 0$, which means that $Ax = \lambda x$, which means that $A^2 x = \lambda^2 x \neq -x$.

Thus, $\det(tI - A)$ has no real roots, which means that its sign is constant. However, its leading coefficient is $1$ (which is positive), so $\lim_{t \to \infty} \det(tI - A) = +\infty$. By the intermediate value theorem, we are forced to conclude that $\det(t I - A)$ is positive for all $t$. Thus, $\det(0I - A) = \det(- A) = \det(A)$ is positive.

So, $\det(A) > 0$ with $|\det(A)| = 1$, which means that $\det(A) = 1$.

Comment: You avoid using complex numbers ("no real roots" do not count I suppose) but you use lots of other things. Of course it is hard to find a proof that is simpler than the second proof in the link.